# Reclassing an instance in Python

Tags: subclass, python

I have a class that is provided to me by an external library. I have created a subclass of this class. I also have an instance of the original class.

I now want to turn this instance into an instance of my subclass without changing any properties that the instance already has (except for those that my subclass overrides anyway).

The following solution seems to work.

```
# This class comes from an external library. I don't (want) to control
# it, and I want to be open to changes that get made to the class
# by the library provider.
class Programmer(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name

    def greet(self):
        print "Hi, my name is %s." % self._name

    def hard_work(self):
        print "The garbage collector will take care of everything."

# This is my subclass.
class C_Programmer(Programmer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(C_Programmer,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.learn_C()

    def learn_C(self):
        self._knowledge = ["malloc","free","pointer arithmetic","curly braces"]

    def hard_work(self):
        print "I'll have to remember " + " and ".join(self._knowledge) + "."

    # The questionable thing: Reclassing a programmer.
    @classmethod
    def teach_C(cls, programmer):
        programmer.__class__ = cls # <-- do I really want to do this?
        programmer.learn_C()


joel = C_Programmer("Joel")
joel.greet()
joel.hard_work()
#>Hi, my name is Joel.
#>I'll have to remember malloc and free and pointer arithmetic and curly braces.

jeff = Programmer("Jeff")

# We (or someone else) makes changes to the instance. The reclassing shouldn't
# overwrite these.
jeff._name = "Jeff A" 

jeff.greet()
jeff.hard_work()
#>Hi, my name is Jeff A.
#>The garbage collector will take care of everything.

# Let magic happen.
C_Programmer.teach_C(jeff)

jeff.greet()
jeff.hard_work()
#>Hi, my name is Jeff A.
#>I'll have to remember malloc and free and pointer arithmetic and curly braces.
```

However, I'm not convinced that this solution doesn't contain any caveats I haven't thought of (sorry for the triple negation), especially because reassigning the magical `__class__` just doesn't feel right. Even if this works, I can't help the feeling there should be a more pythonic way of doing this.

Is there?

---

Edit: Thanks everyone for your answers. Here is what I get from them:

- Although the idea of reclassing an instance by assigning to `__class__` is not a widely used idiom, most answers (4 out of 6 at the time of writing) consider it a valid approach. One anwswer (by ojrac) says that it's "pretty weird at first glance," with which I agree (it was the reason for asking the question). Only one answer (by Jason Baker; with two positive comments & votes) actively discouraged me from doing this, however doing so based on the example use case moreso than on the technique in general.
- None of the answers, whether positive or not, finds an actual technical problem in this method. A small exception is jls who mentions to beware of old-style classes, which is likely true, and C extensions. I suppose that new-style-class-aware C extensions should be as fine with this method as Python itself (presuming the latter is true), although if you disagree, keep the answers coming.

As to the question of how pythonic this is, there were a few positive answers, but no real reasons given. Looking at the Zen (`import this`), I guess the most important rule in this case is "Explicit is better than implicit." I'm not sure, though, whether that rule speaks for or against reclassing this way.

- Using `{has,get,set}attr` seems more explicit, as we are explicitly making our changes to the object instead of using magic.
- Using `__class__ = newclass` seems more explicit because we explicitly say "This is now an object of class 'newclass,' expect a different behaviour" instead of silently changing attributes but leaving users of the object believing they are dealing with a regular object of the old class.

Summing up: From a technical standpoint, the method seems okay; the pythonicity question remains unanswered with a bias towards "yes."

I have accepted Martin Geisler's answer, because the Mercurial plugin example is a quite strong one (and also because it answered a question I even hadn't asked myself yet). However, if there are any arguments on the pythonicity question, I'd still like to hear them. Thanks all so far.

P.S. The actual use case is a UI data control object that needs to grow additional functionality *at runtime*. However, the question is meant to be very general.

Comment: Nice example. Could you perhaps explain in which case you find this pattern useful? I like the idea, but I'm not sure of how it's being useful :)

Comment: @ NicDumZ: Thanks for the question; it's answered in the edit.

Comment: +1 for the example code and the extensive work into the question. It's nice to see.

Comment: For the record, I wasn't necessarily discouraging the use of reclassing in general.  However, it gives me (and apparently you as you started the thread) enough of a bad feeling that I would recommend avoiding it unless there's a compelling reason to.  Bear in mind that Mercurial was designed with this type of thing in mind.  Whatever library you're using probably wasn't.

Comment: Thanks Jason; that's exactly how I took your answer. I will be keeping this in mind. So far, I haven't run into problems since trying it, but I'll watch out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reclassing instances like this is done in [Mercurial](http://selenic.com/mercurial/) (a distributed revision control system) when extensions (plugins) want to change the object that represent the local repository. The object is called `repo` and is initially a `localrepo` instance. It is passed to each extension in turn and, when needed, extensions will define a new class which is a subclass of `repo.__class__` and *change* the class of `repo` to this new subclass!

It looks [like this](http://www.selenic.com/hg/index.cgi/file/d19ab9a56bf4/hgext/bookmarks.py#l229) in code:

```
def reposetup(ui, repo):
    # ...

    class bookmark_repo(repo.__class__): 
        def rollback(self):
            if os.path.exists(self.join('undo.bookmarks')):
                util.rename(self.join('undo.bookmarks'), self.join('bookmarks'))
            return super(bookmark_repo, self).rollback() 

        # ...

    repo.__class__ = bookmark_repo
```

The extension (I took the code from the bookmarks extension) defines a module level function called `reposetup`. Mercurial will call this when initializing the extension and pass a `ui` (user interface) and `repo` (repository) argument.

The function then defines a subclass of whatever class `repo` happens to be. It would *not* suffice to simply subclass `localrepo` since extensions need to be able to extend each other. So if the first extension changes `repo.__class__` to `foo_repo`, the next extension should change `repo.__class__` to a subclass of `foo_repo` and not just a subclass of `localrepo`. Finally the function changes the instanceø's class, just like you did in your code.

I hope this code can show a legitimate use of this language feature. I think it's the only place where I've seen it used in the wild.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure that the use of inheritance is best in this case (at least with regards to "reclassing").  It seems like you're on the right track, but it sounds like composition or aggregation would be best for this.  Here's an example of what I'm thinking of (in untested, pseudo-esque code):

```
from copy import copy

# As long as none of these attributes are defined in the base class,
# this should be safe
class SkilledProgrammer(Programmer):
    def __init__(self, *skillsets):
        super(SkilledProgrammer, self).__init__()
        self.skillsets = set(skillsets)

def teach(programmer, other_programmer):
    """If other_programmer has skillsets, append this programmer's
       skillsets.  Otherwise, create a new skillset that is a copy
       of this programmer's"""
    if hasattr(other_programmer, skillsets) and other_programmer.skillsets:
        other_programmer.skillsets.union(programmer.skillsets)
    else:
        other_programmer.skillsets = copy(programmer.skillsets)
def has_skill(programmer, skill):
    for skillset in programmer.skillsets:
        if skill in skillset.skills
            return True
    return False
def has_skillset(programmer, skillset):
    return skillset in programmer.skillsets


class SkillSet(object):
    def __init__(self, *skills):
        self.skills = set(skills)

C = SkillSet("malloc","free","pointer arithmetic","curly braces")
SQL = SkillSet("SELECT", "INSERT", "DELETE", "UPDATE")

Bob = SkilledProgrammer(C)
Jill = Programmer()

teach(Bob, Jill)          #teaches Jill C
has_skill(Jill, "malloc") #should return True
has_skillset(Jill, SQL)   #should return False
```

You may have to read more about [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) if you aren't familiar with them to get this example.

Comment: +1 Wrapping is always better when dealing with an object provided by an external API.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine.  I've used this idiom plenty of times.  One thing to keep in mind though is that this idea doesn't play well with old-style classes and various C extensions.  Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but since you are using an external library you'll just have to make sure you're not dealing with any old-style classes or C extensions.

Answer (score 2):

"The State Pattern allows an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change it's class." - Head First Design Pattern. Something very similar write Gamma et.al. in their Design Patterns book. (I have it at my other place, so no quote). I think that's the whole point of this design pattern. But if I can change the class of an object at runtime, most of the time i don't need the pattern (there are cases when State Pattern does more than simulate a class change).

Also, changing class at runtime doesn't always work:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def get_val(self):
        return self.val

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        A.__init__(self, val1)
        self.val2 = val2
    def get_val(self):
        return self.val + self.val2


a = A(3)
b = B(4, 6)

print a.get_val()
print b.get_val()

a.__class__ = B

print a.get_val() # oops!
```

Apart from that, I consider changing class at runtime Pythonic and use it from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Heheh, fun example.

"Reclassing" is pretty weird, at first glance. What about the 'copy constructor' approach? You can do this with the Reflection-like `hasattr`, `getattr` and `setattr`. This code will copy everything from one object to another, unless it already exists. If you don't want to copy methods, you can exclude them; see the commented `if`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cow = 2
        self.moose = 6

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = 2
        self.cow = 11

    def from_foo(foo):
        bar = Bar()
        attributes = dir(foo)
        for attr in attributes:
            if (hasattr(bar, attr)):
                break
            value = getattr(foo, attr)
            # if hasattr(value, '__call__'):
            #     break # skip callables (i.e. functions)
            setattr(bar, attr, value)

        return bar
```

All this reflection isn't pretty, but sometimes you need an ugly reflection machine to make cool stuff happen. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This technique seems reasonably Pythonic to me. Composition would also be a good choice, but assigning to `__class__` is perfectly valid (see [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/68429/) for a recipe that uses it in a slightly different way).

Answer (score 0):

In ojrac's answer, the `break` breaks out of the `for`-loop and doesn't test any more attributes.  I think it makes more sense to just use the `if`-statement to decide what to do with each attribute one at a time, and continue through the `for`-loop over all attributes.  Otherwise, I like ojrac's answer, as I too see assigning to `__class__` as weird. (I'm a beginner with Python and as far as I remember this is my first post to StackOverFlow. Thanks for all the great information!!)

So I tried to implement that. I noticed that dir() doesn't list all the attributes.  http://jedidjah.ch/code/2013/9/8/wrong_dir_function/  So I added '**class**', '**doc**', '**module**' and '**init**' to the list of things to add if they're not there already, (although they're probably all already there), and wondered whether there were more things dir misses.  I also noticed that I was (potentially) assigning to '**class**' after having said that was weird.

Answer (score -2):

I will say this is perfectly fine, if it works for you.