# Copy constructor in python?

Tags: python, constructor, copy

Is there a copy constructor in python ? If not what would I do to achieve something similar ?

The situation is that I am using a library and I have extended one of the classes there with extra functionality and I want to be able to convert the objects I get from the library to instances of my own class.

Comment: You might be interested in this question [disclaimer: I was the one who asked it]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990758/reclassing-an-instance-in-python

Comment: Be careful. The warnings posted by some of the answerers are not to be underestimated.

Comment: To it does not look very readable, I am probably changing my code from using inheritance to just encapsulate the other object instead.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I think you want the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

```
import copy

x = copy.copy(y)        # make a shallow copy of y
x = copy.deepcopy(y)    # make a deep copy of y
```

you can control copying in much the same way as you control [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle).

Comment: `deepcopy` works well for doing this external to the class definition. But @Zitrax wants to do this within his class definition so that the new instance inherits the attributes (data) from an object of a different (parent) type (class).

Answer (score 46):

In python the copy constructor can be defined using default arguments.  Lets say you want the normal constructor to run the function `non_copy_constructor(self)` and the copy constructor should run `copy_constructor(self, orig)`.  Then you can do the following:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, orig=None):
        if orig is None:
            self.non_copy_constructor()
        else:
            self.copy_constructor(orig)
    def non_copy_constructor(self):
        # do the non-copy constructor stuff
    def copy_constructor(self, orig):
        # do the copy constructor

a=Foo()  # this will call the non-copy constructor
b=Foo(a) # this will call the copy constructor
```

Answer (score 26):

A simple example of my usual implementation of a copy constructor:

```
import copy

class Foo:

  def __init__(self, data):
    self._data = data

  @classmethod
  def from_foo(cls, class_instance):
    data = copy.deepcopy(class_instance._data) # if deepcopy is necessary
    return cls(data)
```

Comment: Nice. This would work like `Foo.from_foo(foo)`. A further refinement would be to make this work for `Foo(foo)`, which is what the OP @Zitrax probably wants.

Comment: The reasons I don't like this is because 1. It forces `__init__` to take `data` as input, and is not flexible for more types 2. It doesn't allow overloading 3. `__init__` is public, which you may not want if you have other constructor types.

Answer (score 14):

For your situation, I would suggest writing a class method (or it could be a static method or a separate function) that takes as an argument an instance of the library's class and returns an instance of your class with all applicable attributes copied over.

Comment: by iterating through `__dict__` perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

Building on @Godsmith's [train of thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441776/623735) and addressing @Zitrax's need (I think) to do the data copy for all attributes within the constructor:

```
class ConfusionMatrix(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, df, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Check if `df` looks like a `ConfusionMatrix`
            # Could check `isinstance(df, ConfusionMatrix)`
            # But might miss some "ConfusionMatrix-elligible" `DataFrame`s
            assert((df.columns == df.index).all())
            assert(df.values.dtype == int)
            self.construct_copy(df, *args, **kwargs)
            return
        except (AssertionError, AttributeError, ValueError):
            pass
        # df is just data, so continue with normal constructor here ...

    def construct_copy(self, other, *args, **kwargs):
        # construct a parent DataFrame instance
        parent_type = super(ConfusionMatrix, self)
        parent_type.__init__(other)
        for k, v in other.__dict__.iteritems():
            if hasattr(parent_type, k) and hasattr(self, k) and getattr(parent_type, k) == getattr(self, k):
                continue
            setattr(self, k, deepcopy(v))
```

This [`ConfusionMatrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) class inherits a `pandas.DataFrame` and adds a ton of other attributes and methods that need to be recomputed unless the `other` matrix data can be copied over. Searching for a solution is how I found this question.

Comment: Note that this approach differs from copy constructors of many other languages in that it won't call copy-constructors of attributes.

Comment: Also note if `v` is a numpy array or derivative, comparison with `==` will raise an error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. If you have attributes that may be numpy array-like, a non-failing comparison (that also works with regular attributes like ints, strs, etc.) is `np.array_equal`

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar situation differing in that the new class only needs to copy attributes. Thus using @Dunham's idea and adding some specificity to @meisterluk's suggestion, @meisterluk's "copy_constructor" method could be:

```
from copy import deepcopy
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, myOne=1, other=None):
    self.two = 2
    if other <> None:
        assert isinstance(other, Foo), "can only copy instances of Foo"
        self.__dict__ = deepcopy(other.__dict__)
    self.one = myOne

def __repr__(self):
    out = ''
    for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
        out += '{:>4s}: {}, {}\n'.format(k,v.__class__,v)
    return out

def bar(self):
    pass

foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo('one', foo1)

print '\nfoo1\n',foo1
print '\nfoo2\n',foo2
```

The output:

```
foo1
 two: <type 'int'>, 2
 one: <type 'int'>, 1


foo2
 two: <type 'int'>, 2
 one: <type 'str'>, one
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution probably repeats some of the previous ones in a simple form. I don't know how it is "pythocally" right, but it works and was quite convenient in the certain case I used it.

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, code=None, name=None, attrs=None):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.attrs = {} if attrs is None else attrs


    def copy(self, attrs=None):
        new_attrs = {k: v.copy() for k, v in self.attrs.items()} if attrs is None else attrs
        return Entity(code=self.code, name=self.name, attrs=new_attrs)
```

Usage:

```
new_entity = entity.copy()
```

This is a more complicated version that allows to interfere in the copying process. I used it in only one place. Also note that objects contained in `self.attrs` also have such kind of "copying constructor".

This solution is not generic but is very simple and provides quite much control.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve like this code
without using any copy module
Python dosen't support method overloding
so we can not make copy constructor ##

```
class student():
    name: str
    age: int

    def __init__(self, other=None):
        if other != None and isinstance(other, student):
            self.name = other.name
            self.age = other.age
        elif not(isinstance(other,student)) and other!=None:
            raise TypeError
    def printInfo(s):
        print(s.name, s.age)
```

Comment: That doesn't extend a base class though. Initializing an object from a copy constructor means that you can have a sublcass B of class A being initialized from an instance of class A. Class B in this case would have all methods/properties of A, plus its own, and will be initialized from an existing instance of A.

Comment: This example only for copy not for deep copy. In copy we just copy properties of object not whole object.