# Is this the equivalent of a copy constructor in Python?

Tags: python

I'm reviewing some old python code and came accross this 'pattern' frequently:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, other = None):
        if other:
            self.__dict__ = dict(other.__dict__)
```

Is this how a copy constructor is typically implemented in Python?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241148/copy-constructor-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to copy all attributes from one object to another one. However note that:

- The object passed to the `__init__` method may have any type (not the same type as the object being created).
- Only object attributes are copied (class attributes and methods are not).

Answer (score 5):

Note that the attributes aren't copied, they are *shared*.

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.x=[1,2,3]
>>> b = Foo(a)
>>> b.x[2] = 4
>>> a.x
[1, 2, 4]
```