# How To Copy All Properties of Class Instance To New Instance

Tags: python, class

How would I copy all the properties of a class to a new instance of the class.
In the example below, with the way python works, when I use b=a, it assigns b and a to the same memory address. When i make a change to "b" the change is also made to "a."
[Both elements of the list are stored at the same address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhKq8.png)

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, name="Name",data=[]):
        self.name=name
        self.data=data




list=[]
a = test("First Name",["DATA1","DATA2","DATA3"])
b=a
list.append(a)
list.append(b)
```

I'm wanting to achieve something similar to how the list class allows you to do this to copy the list to a new memory address.

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=list(list1)
```

So in my case.

```
a = test("First Name",["DATA1","DATA2","DATA3"])
b=test(a)
```

without having to

```
b=test(a.name,a.data)
```

*EDIT*

Id like to achive the same effect as

```
 b=copy.deepcopy(a)
```

but through this usage.

```
b=test(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy constructor in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241148/copy-constructor-in-python)

Comment: copy works for what I need but id like to achieve the same result without copy. just like how the list class uses list2=list(list1) id like to be able to b=test(a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This achieved what I was wanting to do.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(somearg, self.__class__):
            self.__dict__ = somearg.__dict__.copy()
        else:
            self.var = arg
```

Usage:

```
a=Test(123)
b=Test(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `copy`:

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: well actually. Though that achieved the result I wanted. how would I write my class to work similar to the list2=list(list1)   where b=test(a) without using the copy class.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a copy constructor. For example...

```
import copy

class Foo:

  def __init__(self, data):
    self._data = data

  @classmethod
  def from_foo(cls, class_instance):
    data = copy.deepcopy(class_instance._data)
    return cls(data)
```

Comment: copy constructor was what i needed to be looking for. i just didnt know what it was called. thanks