# How to make a python objects self or attribute not get assigned to the referencer object when it is references?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, cpython, pythoninterpreter

I want when a object is referenced by another, the refernecer's self object or one of it's attributes to be different at the referencer object

This is what I want to do:

```
class MyClass:
    .
    .
    .
    .

a = MyClass()
b = a
print(b is a) #must print false
print(b == a) #must print true

#or
a = MyClass()
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) #must print false
print(b.attr == a.attr) #must print true
```

How can I achieve this, normally the when an assignment is made like `a = b`, `b` is a reference to `a`, any help would be appreciated, I want `b` to be a copy/deepcopy of `a`, same for the attribute

Thanks from now for the people who will answer the question

Note: I’m using CPython (the official implemention of Python) version Python 3.8

I'm open for using dark magic

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to do `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` ?

Comment: the question about a copy constructor in python was actually asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241148/copy-constructor-in-python , you can take one of the answers there

Comment: Python isn't like C++. Assignment in Python is an operation on the *namespace or container* containing the assignment target. Your `MyClass` instance does not actually participate in the operation `b = a` in any way.

Comment: Well @TomWojcik , The thing I’m trying to make is, when I do `a = b`, I don’t want `b` to cause `del a` not get deleted (from memory), maybe I can use `weakrefs` to the object itself and store the real object in an attribute of the real object, but I don’t want the attribute to get copied to `b`, I want sys.get_reference_count() (My memory could be wrong about the name of the function) to return 2 (The real object and the reference at the function local variable which is deleted after the function returns the value) so the original object will always have one copy

Comment: You cant change semant of assign operator, you can overload <<= get closer to the syntax that you want

Comment: @geckos I did not know that we can overload the assignment operator in python, can you shortly tell how can I do it?

Comment: Well @ArcticFox its not assignment operators, they are called augmented arithmetic assigments, you have to implement one of these methods https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__

Comment: You can't change the semantics of assignment. Almost certainly, you have no good reason to do so to begin with. Just explicitly copy.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't try to do anything with overloading assignment as that's not very pythonic. Either use the `deepcopy` function or make a copy "constructor". Then override the `__eq__` function so that the two variables test equal.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading an assignment operator in the way you are suggesting is not very pythonic.

The assignment operator in Python is meant to refer to the same variable, and not to create a copy.

So, such an object may not behave as expected in some situations, such as the results of `hash(object.attr)` or from using the `pickle` module on such an object.

However, if you are up for some dark magic...

---

To be clear, I am providing this answer just to show Python does offer the ability to do such things.

---

One approach would be to use the `__getattribute__()` function to create a copy of any attribute when it is accessed.

```
import copy

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = ["foo", "bar"]
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        """Access an attribute of this class"""
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        return copy.copy(attr)

a = MyClass()
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints False
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True
```

More information on `__getattribute__()` can be found here: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

---

Alternatively, `property()` could be used to do this only for a single attribute on a class.

```
class MyClass:
def __init__(self):
    self.__attr = ["foo", "bar"]

@property
def attr(self):
    """Get the attribute."""
    # Copy could be used instead
    # This works too, if we assume the attribute supports slicing
    return self.__attr[:]

@attr.setter
def attr(self, value):
    """Setting the attribute."""
    # Makes assignment work on this attribute
    # a.attr = []
    # a.attr is a.attr (False)
    self.__attr = value

a = MyClass()
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints False
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True
```

---

These solutions work for most object types. But this will actually fail under some situations. This is because some strings and some integers will be marked as having the same identity.

Such as `4 is 2*2` which will be `True`, but

```
a = -6
b = -6
print(a is b) # Will print False
```

This is called "interning" and is discussed briefly in the `sys` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=intern#sys.intern

According to Real Python: https://realpython.com/lessons/intern-objects/

> in CPython 3.7, integers between -5 and 256 are interned, as with
> strings that are less than 20 characters and contain only ASCII
> letters, digits, or underscores.

For example, if `attr = 5` or `attr = 'foo'` then both approaches above fail.

```
a = MyClass()
a.attr = 5
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints True
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True
```

This can be circumvented by wrapping these types in a subclass. According to RealPython, only strings and some integers need to be modified. The catch with this approach would be a type comparison would fail:

```
print(type(b.attr) is type(a.attr)) # prints False
```

So if you wanted to wrap the objects, making sure the `is` operation always fails, you could do this:

```
import copy
from collections import UserString # Because of course Python has this built in

class UserInt(int): pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, attr = ["foo", "bar"]):
        self.attr = attr
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        """Access an attribute of this class"""
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)

        if isinstance(attr, int) and -5 <= attr <= 256:
            return UserInt(attr) # Prevent a.attr is b.attr if this is an int
        elif isinstance(attr, str):
            return UserString(attr) # Prevent a.attr is b.attr for strings
        #else
        return copy.copy(attr)

a = MyClass()
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints False
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True

a.attr = 7
b = a
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints False
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True

a.attr = "Hello"
print(b.attr is a.attr) # prints False
print(b.attr == a.attr) # prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

may use for ex: copy.copy and copy.deepcopy...

for python3:

```
print(MyClass() == MyClass())
print(MyClass() is MyClass())
```

outs:

```
False
False
>>>
```

*and other shaman methods will be analogue ...*

Comment: Python 3 also has `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()`. What can't be do in Python 3?