# When where and how can i change the __class__ attr of an object?

Tags: python, python-datamodel

I'd like to be able to do:

```
>>> class a(str):
...     pass
...
>>> b = a()
>>> b.__class__ = str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990758/reclassing-an-instance-in-python

Comment: I'd like to say that this is a fairly bad message from the interpreter, since the term "heap type" isn't familiar to most Python programmers and there doesn't appear to be any way in Python 3 to create a class whose instances have an assignable __class__. Or at least I haven't found one.

Comment: @holdenweb  https://bugs.python.org/issue4600

Comment: Nice one. I meant, of course, an assignable `__class__` attribute.

Comment: The issue here isn't when or where the attribute is assigned; it's *what* you want to change it *to*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved it in this way:

```
>>> class C(str):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         if name == '__class__':
...             return str
...         else:
...             return super(C, self).__getattribute__(name)
...         
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__class__
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 6):

Python 2 doesn't have a unified object hierarchy (ie. not everything is derived from the `object`). Anything that is part of this hierarchy can be played with via `__class__`, but those that aren't cannot be modified in this way (or at all, really). Python 2 calls these "types" rather than "classes", and they're hard-coded in C. Examples of types are `str`, `int`, `float`, `list`, `tuple`, etc. This means that you cannot use types in the same ways as classes, for example you cannot change the class of an instance of a type, you cannot add, remove or modify methods of types, etc. The following transcript shows the difference in behaviour between types such as `str` (hard-coded, non-dynamic C constructs) and classes I've called A and B (changeable, dynamic, Python constructs):

```
>>> str
<type 'str'>
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> A
<class __main__.A at 0xb747f2cc>
>>> a
<__main__.A instance at 0xb747e74c>
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(str)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(type(a))
<type 'type'>
>>> type(type(A))
<type 'type'>
>>> A.foo = lambda self,x: x
>>> a.foo(10)
10
>>> A().foo(5)
5
>>> str.foo = lambda self,x: x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
>>> 'abc'.foo(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> class B:
...     pass
... 
>>> a.__class__
<class __main__.A at 0xb747f2cc>
>>> a.__class__ = B
>>> a
<__main__.B instance at 0xb747e74c>
>>> 'abc'.__class__
<type 'str'>
>>> 'abc'.__class__ = B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ must be set to new-style class, not 'classobj' object
>>> class B(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> 'abc'.__class__ = B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

Comment: Everything in python 2 is a object instance.

Comment: You mean that not all classes are instances of type.

Comment: In 3.x, the built-in types are referred to the same way as user-defined types (both say "class" rather than "type" in object representations), and they are considered subclasses of `object`, but the issue identified by OP persists (because the types are still implemented in a different way with a fundamentally different memory layout).

Answer (score -1):

Only classes that were defined with a `class` keyword could be used for `__class__` attribute assignment:

```
>>> class C:
    pass

>>> class D:
    pass

>>> C().__class__ = D
>>>
```

Comment: That´s not what they say here:http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/449635-assigning-self-__class__

Comment: In fact, I think `__mro__` is the only read-only attribute there.

Comment: I think this is not total true. You may have class A(str) and you cant assign A.

Comment: See http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg52950.html for a list of differences between types that might give troubles.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this way!

```
>>> class C(str):
...     __class__ = str
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__class__
<class 'str'>
```