# Subclass super returning self should return subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to extend the `datetime.date` class do allow adding `int`s instead of working with `timedelta` objects:

```
class Date(datetime.date):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            other = datetime.timedelta(days=other)
        return super(Date, self).__add__(other)
```

The problem is that the `__add__()` method above will return an instance of `datetime.date` instead of a `Date`.

From my understanding, there is no way to make `super().__add__()` aware of the `Date` type. The most elegant solution is to copy the entire `__add__()` method from `datetime.date` and add my extra bit of code. Is there a way to cast a `datetime.date` object to a `Date` object in the `Date.__add__()` method?

Here is a snippet to highlight the issue:

```
D = Date(2000,1,1)
d = D + 1
type(d) # datetime.date instead of Date
```

EDIT: My first solution after looking at [datetime.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/datetime/datetime.py) (search for "class date") is to do this:

```
class Date(datetime.date):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            other = datetime.timedelta(days=other)
        d = super(Date, self).__add__(other)
        self.__year = d.year
        self.__month = d.month
        self.__day = d.day
        return self # this is of type datetime.date
```

OK, I thought I'd point out that my first try was this:

```
class Date(datetime.date):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            other = datetime.timedelta(days=other)
        d = super(Date, self).__add__(other)
        d.__class__ = Date
        return d
```

which will not work because (as I suspected) the datetime module is in C and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013280/when-where-and-how-can-i-change-the-class-attr-of-an-object-in-python) for such types you cannot assign to `__class__`. I am a bit confused what the code in datetime.py is for then.

Comment: What about something like `return Date(super(Date, self).__add__(other)`?

Comment: @bimsapi Doesn't work, unfortunatly. Seems like `datetime.date`'s constructor isn't nice like that.

Comment: Of course `super` methods return a `datetime.date`, **that's the superclass**! You could create a `Date` from it, though; `d = super(Date, self).__add__(other); return Date(d.year, d.month, d.day)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding, just create another `Date` object from `datetime.date` and return it like this

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            other = datetime.timedelta(days=other)
        result = super(Date, self).__add__(other)
        return Date(result.year, result.month, result.day)
```

And here is a test,

```
D = Date(2000, 1, 1) + 1
print(type(D), D)
# (<class '__main__.Date'>, Date(2000, 1, 2))
```

Comment: The first change doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: @matsjoyce Oh yeah. That is not necessary. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep, works - it's an elegant version of my first Edit above :)

Comment: @s5s Actually, your edit makes the `+` a mutable operation, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the add() method above will return an instance of datetime.date instead of a Date.

It will, but that's why you're using super(), after all: you really want to call the super classes' method.

You could just call your own class's copy constructor!

> The most elegant solution is to copy the entire add() method from datetime.date and add my extra bit of code.

That can't really be called an elegant solution, I think. Also, I think the datetime module is C.

Comment: Yup, it is C. There is a `datetime.py`, but all the methods are blank and return None.

Comment: OK, I thought it's C which will explain why I cannot just overwrite self.__class__ = Date in Date.__add__() before returning the object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `super(Subclass, self).__add__(other)` may return `Subclass` instance:

```
class Base(object):
    __slots__ = 'n'
    def __new__(cls, n):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.n = n
        return self
    @classmethod
    def fromordinal(cls, n):
        return cls(n)
    def __add__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'n'):
            return self.fromordinal(self.n + other.n)
        return NotImplemented
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{cls}({arg})".format(cls=self.__class__.__name__, arg=self.n)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.n == other.n

class Subclass(Base):
    __slots__ = ['_secret']
    def __add__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, '_secret'):
            other = self.fromordinal(other._secret)
        return super(Subclass, self).__add__(other)


a = Subclass(1)
b = Subclass(2)
c = Subclass(2)
c._secret = 3
print(a + b)
print(a + c)
assert (a + b) == Subclass(3)
assert (a + c) == Subclass(4)
assert b == c and (a + b) != (a + c) and type(a + b) == type(a + c) == Subclass
```

But `datetime.date.__add__` method is hardcoded to return `datetime.date` instances even for `datetime.date` subclasses. [In CPython, it is implemented in C](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b312b256931e/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l2547) that for  performance reasons does not call (possibly) pure Python `__add__` method from a subclass. Pure Python `datetime.py` that might be used by other Python implementations such as Pypy, IronPython, Jython does not invoke subclass methods for compatibility with CPython.

Comment: So what does the datetime.py file do? Is it just python wrappers around C code?

Comment: @s5s: see Python issue7989: [Add pure Python implementation of datetime module to CPython](http://bugs.python.org/issue7989): *The stated long-term goal of the stdlib is to minimize the C extension modules to only those that have to be written in C (modules can still have performance enhancing extension back-ends). Since datetime does not meet that requirement it's not a matter of "if" but "when" datetime will get a pure Python version and use the extension code only for performance.* ... *The key thing to remember is that this is so the VMs other than CPython are not treated as second-class.*