# Decorator/Wrapper enhancing method internally called

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, decorator

**NOTE:** I'm not asking about common python decorators, but about the decorator design pattern.

I want to write a decorator that is able to modify a function called by the concrete component, the following code sample illustrates my problem:

```
In [2]: class Animal:
   ...:     def sound(self):
   ...:         raise NotImplementedError
   ...:         
   ...:     def speak(self):
   ...:         print(self.sound())
   ...:         

In [3]: class Dog(Animal):    
   ...:     def sound(self):
   ...:         return 'woof!'
   ...:     

In [4]: class Bigfy:
   ...:     def __init__(self, animal):
   ...:         self.animal = animal
   ...:         
   ...:     def sound(self):
   ...:         return self.animal.sound().upper()
   ...:     
   ...:     def speak(self):
   ...:         return self.animal.speak()
   ...:     

In [5]: dog = Dog()
   ...: dog.speak()
   ...: 
woof!

In [6]: big_dog = Bigfy(Dog())
   ...: big_dog.sound()
   ...: 
Out[6]: 'WOOF!'

In [7]: big_dog.speak()
woof! # I want 'WOOF!' here
```

The method that I want to enhance functionality is `sound`, but this method is not directly called by the client and is instead internally called by `speak` so all the wraps on `sound` take no effect.

Is it possibly to achieve what I want using the decorator design pattern? If not what design pattern I should take a look?

---

**Edit**: Thanks everyone for your quick answers, following the pattern from @FHTMitchell I reached the following solution:

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: class Animal:
   ...:     def sound(self):
   ...:         raise NotImplementedError
   ...:         
   ...:     def speak(self):
   ...:         print(self.sound())
   ...:         
   ...:     # Key change    
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def unwrapped(self):
   ...:         return self
   ...:     

In [3]: class Dog(Animal):    
   ...:     def sound(self):
   ...:         return 'woof!'
   ...:     

In [4]: class BaseWrapper:
   ...:     def __new__(cls, animal, **kwargs):
   ...:         self = super().__new__(cls)
   ...:         self.__init__(animal, **kwargs)
   ...:         
   ...:         # Automatically points unwrapped methods to last wrapper
   ...:         for attr in dir(animal):
   ...:             # Don't get magic methods
   ...:             if attr.startswith('__') or attr.startswith('old'):
   ...:                 continue
   ...:                 
   ...:             value = getattr(animal, attr)
   ...:             if inspect.ismethod(value):
   ...:                 # Store old method 
   ...:                 setattr(self, 'old_' + attr, value)
   ...:                 # Points to new method
   ...:                 setattr(animal.unwrapped, attr, getattr(self, attr))
   ...:             
   ...:         return self
   ...:     
   ...:     def __init__(self, animal):
   ...:         self.animal = animal
   ...:         
   ...:     # Delegate all non-implemented attrs calls to wrapped class
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, name):
   ...:         return getattr(self.animal, name)
   ...:     
   ...:     # Helps with editor auto-completion
   ...:     def __dir__(self):
   ...:         dir_list = super().__dir__()
   ...:         dir_list.extend(self.animal.__dir__())
   ...: 
   ...:         return dir_list
   ...:     

In [5]: class Bigify(BaseWrapper):
   ...:     def sound(self):        
   ...:         return self.old_sound().upper()
   ...:     

In [6]: class Angrify(BaseWrapper):
   ...:     def sound(self):        
   ...:         return self.old_sound() + '!!!'
   ...:     

In [7]: class Happify(BaseWrapper):
   ...:     def sound(self):        
   ...:         return self.old_sound() + ' =)'
   ...:     

In [8]: big_angry_dog = Happify(Angrify(Bigify(Dog())))
   ...: big_angry_dog.speak()
   ...: 
WOOF!!!! =)
```

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for subclassing. (And note that decorator in Python means something different; better to refer to this as a wrapper.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I want to add functionalities at run-time, so no subclassing =/

Comment: Is this the same situation? [reclassing an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990758/reclassing-an-instance-in-python)

Comment: @Quazar this is python, everything happens at runtime, even class definitions. What exactly do you mean? You only have access to instances?

Comment: @FHTMitchell, I mean that I want to user to be able to add new functionalities as they wish, for example, they first build a dog, then make it big, then make it brown, etc... Again, I'm open to other design patterns that achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple way

Using different design pattern -- use dynamic attributes:

```
class Animal:

    sound: str = None
    big: bool = False
    color: str = None    

    def speak(self) -> str:
        if self.sound is None:
             raise NotImplemnetedError()
        return self.sound.upper() if self.big else self.sound
```

Then you can have a dog (which all woof)

```
class Dog(Animal):    
     sound = 'woof!'
```

and an instance can be big

```
mydog = Dog()
mydog.big = True
mydog.speak()
# WOOF!
```

and be brown

```
mydog.color = 'brown'
mydog.color  # 'brown'
```

---

#### Complex way

If you do want to edit instance methods, you can do it like so (using your pattern from the OP)

```
import types
import functools

def bigify(inst: Animal) -> None:
    '''Note this modifies the object in place. Implement a `__copy__()` 
    method and call `copy.copy` on inst and return new inst if you 
    don't want this behaviour.
    '''

    old_method = inst.sound  # need to store the old one somewhere

    @functools.wraps(inst.sound)  # preserve __doc__
    def inner(self):
        return old_method().upper()

    inst.sound = types.MethodType(inner, inst)

bigify(dog)

dog.speak()  # WOOF!
```